# Next.js - how to pass a visitor ip into the frontend

Tags: next.js

I have to send a user IP into the logging service on page load. I use static mode in my next.js app.

I have an idea to use an edge function to get visitor IP, pass it as header and then read this value on the frontend. How can I read it? Is there any other reasonable option to pass information like IP or geo into the frontend?

Thanks!

Comment: I would utilize an api service to do this, most provide 10k+ free per month and then you can cale up as needed -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can get IP by using [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) but this approach change page from static to server render [more info](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization). You use it inside the page file like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

context in this case contains user ip you can get it like this:

```
const ip = context.req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || context.req.socket.remoteAddress;
```

and than you can pass it to the frontend or send another request with this ip:

```
 export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      const ip = context.req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || context.req.socket.remoteAddress;
      return {
        props: { ip }, // will be passed to the page component as props
      }
    }
```

and then catch it and use it in your component:

```
export default function MyPage({ ip }) {...}
```

### Sending ip from getServerSideProps to the server

you can get ip also on you backend if you using Node.js and express inside **req**:

```
const myFn = (req, res, next) => {
    const ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.socket.remoteAddress;
}
```

but if you send request from getServerSideProps there will be your Next.js **server** ip not user ip. So you need manually add header with ip when you sending request from the getServerSideProps for example with axios (it is better to use [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) for convenience):

```
axios.post("/some/route", {...},{
    headers: { "client-ip": ctx.req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || ctx.req.socket.remoteAddress },
  });
```

and than on the Node.js backend:

```
const myFn = (req, res, next) => {
    const ip = req.headers["client-ip"] || req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.socket.remoteAddress;
}
```

and with all this you can get your user ip in all scenarios.

### Note

When you working with localhost you will get **::1** as ip but in production it works as expected.